# Getting an Error opening pcap file in wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap

While trying to open a pcap file, I am getting below error.

**pcap: network type 512 unknown or unsupported**

Can anyone explain me what the 512 refers to ?

Comment: The [link layer type](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) which is field network in the [pcap header](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat#global-header). Are you sure your pcap is valid? How did you create it? Maybe it is corrupted?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am trying to create a pcap header using dummy data following the standard header format in .Net as shown below: – 

                writer.Write(0xa1b2c3d4); // Magic Number
                writer.Write(0x0200); // PCAP version 2.4
                writer.Write(0x0200); // timezone offset
                writer.Write(0x0200); //  timestamp
          
                writer.Write(0x0200); // Snap Length
                writer.Write(0x0200); // Link-Layer Type

Comment: ` writer.Write(0x0200); // Link-Layer Type ` - so there you have your 512 (0x0200). The link layer is important to interpret the actual packets sniffed, so the program which should interpret the data needs to understand what this link layer means. You cannot just use some arbitrary value but must use the layer type matching your packet data.

Answer (score 2):

As Steffen Ullrich says, you can't use an arbitrary link-layer type value.  The link he provided for [the link layer type](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) goes to a page which lists the valid link-layer type values, with descriptions of most them.  See which one corresponds to the data you want to put into the pcap file and use that.